# How to Resizing image after insertimage on summernote content

Tags: text-editor, summernote

I'm using `summernote 0.8.9`. 
I need to know how to change the image with 100% after inserted to `summernote` content. how can I fix this problem?

This is the code, I'm using.

```
<script>$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#summernote").summernote({
            placeholder: 'Enter directions here...',
            height: 300,
            callbacks: {
                onImageUpload : function(files, editor, welEditable) {

                    for(var i = files.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                        sendFile(files[i], this);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
    function sendFile(file, el) {
        var form_data = new FormData();
        form_data.append('file', file);
        $.ajax({
            data: form_data,
            type: "POST",
            url: 'editor-upload.php',
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(url) {
                $(el).summernote('editor.insertImage', url);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```